is ranger capitalized in this sentence?

"You don’t need to worry for your safety; the rangers will take care of that."

The speaker is assuring the listener of his safety. "Rangers" mentioned here are the forest rangers of the state who will be accompanying the listener to the forest. Speaker is not talking about the forest ranger department as a whole. Listener is a traveler new to the state while the speaker is a native.
Will rangers be capitalized? Is usage of 'the' before rangers appropriate?

The rangers is appropriate and would  be understood to refer to those accompanying the person, though possibly others might be involved as well.  If the speaker wanted to make perfectly clear that only those accompanying the person would be seeing to their safety, and the rangers were present when the person was speaking, it could be these rangers.  If the rangers are not present there, but perhaps some distance away yet  still in view, it would be those rangers.
Upper case The Rangers would refer to the corps as a whole, the organization.  If you wanted to state the duties of the organization:

The Rangers ensure the safety of visitors, protect the park, and enforce park rules.

You could refer to members of the corps as follows:

The park has rules. Please obey the rangers you meet while in the park if they  give you any instructions about which trails you may take.  Sometimes a trail that is normally open will be temporarily closed when there is some risk of injury, such as from falling branches in windy conditions or a landslide after heavy rains.

